# Phonegap 2.6 android inappbrowser opens on self despite _blank being passed

Tags: android, url, cordova, sencha-touch-2, inappbrowser

I am using PhoneGap 2.6.0 with Sencha Touch 2.2 on Android 4.0.3. I am calling the InAppBrowser to open a share url to facebook like so:

```
window.open(encodeURI('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.mycoolapp.com/&t=Everyone check this out'), '_blank', 'location=no');
```

However, instead of opening the InAppBrowser with the UI, it opens on top of my app screen without any 'OK' button like on iOS or any way to close and go back.

I am able to go back with the standard Android OS back button.

Is there any way to get the url bar and the OK button to show on the Android InAppBrowser for PhoneGap?

Answer (score 0):

As per [window.open](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser) section in docs, you have to give `location=yes' to show location bar. Regarding type of window, do you see any difference when you pass '_self' and '_blank'?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a problem with your Access-origin in `res/xml/config.xml` ([PhoneGap 2.6.0 Domain Whitelist Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide))...?

Answer (score 0):

As others stated, for android you have to specify location=yes and no you can't get riddle of the location bar *and* mantain back button. 
But if you are on Android *why* do you have to keep it?
Being able to coming back with physical back button is the preferred behaviour by design in Android.